# Only superuser is getting logged in but user is not getting logged

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms

I have created a django app with signin,login and logout.i have executed `pyhon manage.py` createsuper user to create a superuser.if i login with those credentials it is getting logged but when i am creating the credentials using custom signin form the user is getting saved in the database but the user is not getting logged in with login form.

```
models.py
--------
class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
     def create_user(self, fname,lname,username, password):
          """
          Creates and saves a User with the given username, date of
          birth and password.
          """
          if not username:
               raise ValueError('Users must have an username')
          user = self.model(username=username,fname=fname,lname=lname)
          user.set_password(password)
          user.save(using=self._db)
          return user


     def create_superuser(self, fname,lname,username, password,email=None):
          """
          Creates and saves a superuser with the given username and password.
          """
          user = self.create_user(
               fname=fname,
               lname=lname,
               username=username,
               password=password,
          )
          user.is_admin = True
          user.is_superuser = True
          user.save(using=self._db)
          return user

class Event(AbstractBaseUser):
     fname = models.CharField('fname', max_length=120)
     lname = models.CharField('lname',max_length=120)
     username = models.CharField('username',max_length = 60,unique=True)
     password = models.CharField('password',max_length=120,default='pavi@2789')

     USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
     REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['fname','lname']

     objects = MyUserManager()

     def __unicode__(self):
          return self.username

     class Meta:
          # managed = False
          db_table = "user"
forms.py
-------
#User Registration Form
class UserRegistrationForm(forms.Form):
    fname = forms.CharField(required=True,label='FirstName',max_length=32,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'autocomplete':'off'}))

    lname = forms.CharField(required=True,label='LastName',max_length=32,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'autocomplete':'off'}))

    username = forms.CharField(required = True,label = 'Username',max_length = 32,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'autocomplete':'off'}))

    password = forms.CharField(required = True,label = 'Password',max_length = 32,min_length=8,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'autocomplete':'off'}))

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ('FirstName', 'LastName', 'username', 'password',)
view.py:
------
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            userObj = form.cleaned_data
            username = userObj['username']
            password = userObj['password']
            fname = userObj['fname']
            lname = userObj['lname']
            print (username,password,fname,lname)
            if(len(password)<8):
                # messages.error(request,"This password length should be minimum 8 characters")
                raise ValidationError("This password length should be minimum 8 characters ")
            if not (User.objects.filter(username=username).exists()):
                p = Event(fname=fname, lname=lname, username=username)
                p.set_password(password)
                p.save()
                # return HttpResponseRedirect('Login.html')
                return redirect('/Login/')
            else:
                raise forms.ValidationError('Looks like a username with that username or password already exists')
    else:
        form = UserRegistrationForm()
    return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form':form})
def Login(request):
    form = login_form(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
        password = form.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        print (username,password)
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        print('user is', user)
        if user is not None and user.is_active:
            print ('entered loop')
            login(request,user)
            return redirect('/home/')
        else:
            print ("username and password are incorrect ")
    else:
        form = login_form()
    return render(request, 'Login.html', {'form': form})
```

I have declared `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'auth.User'` in settings.py

i have tried using get_user_model() also but it is not working.

Comment: seems like permission issue. can you please add your view's code too.

Comment: @Shakil i have added the view code.

Comment: redirection is not working is this your problem ?

Comment: can you please also add login function code of your view.

Comment: If you can provide more code like of forms.py then I will modify my answer if anything different comes up

Comment: also what you are getting when you do this "print (username,password)"

Comment: Username and password are printing but after authenticate function it is saying user as none.

Answer (score 0):

After you register new user in sign up form,

1. Login to Django admin using superuser account and navigate to the users table.
2. Select the newly created user.
3. Check the activate checkbox.

Then try to log in as a new user in different browser or chrome incognito mode.

OR

Enable the new user active by default as shown below:

```
 def create_user(self, fname, lname,username, password):
      """
      Creates and saves a User with the given username, date of
      birth, password and keep the user activated by default
      """
      user.is_active = True
      user.save(using=self._db)
      return user
```

Comment: eventhough i  have added user.is_active = True the user cannot be able to login.

Answer (score 0):

I check few resources and I think the problem is in

```
    username = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
    password = form.cleaned_data.get("password1") #here
```

May be if you try with password it will work

PS: I will suggest you that if you not implementing not hole lot another and if Django authentication work fine then you can inherit it's property and use them directly into your code.